# How is inputs from 1 layer in a feed forward fully connected network combined to become 1 output in the subsequent layer?

Tags: python, tensorflow, machine-learning, keras, keras-layer

Im trying to understand the general process of a neural network on a bit less superficial level, and i have trouble understanding this:

Lets say i have a network with an input layer and a hidden layer (forget output layer).
The input layer has 20 nodes and the hidden layer has 10 nodes. My input is a 100x1 vector (flattened image).

To my understanding the input is processed in each node where we find the dot product between input 100x1 and a corresponding weight matrix of size 1x100. The output is a scalar.

My question is then; In the subsequent layer, assuming network is fully connected, the 10 nodes will receive 20 inputs. What happens with these inputs before they are processed in the nodes? Are they summed, are they concatenated or something else?

If the nodes in this layer is only to produce 1 output each, they have to combine the inputs i assume.

Comment: no, if you pass from a input layer of 100 and the subsequent layer of 20 neurons, the affine transformation is done using a matrix 100x20, not 100x1

Comment: @AlbertoSinigaglia My input layer has 20 nodes, and my raw data is a flattened image thats been preprocessed to be a vector of 100 rows x 1 columns.